# Beamer remove literature heading

Tags: beamer, lyx

For some reason, even though my literature frame is called `Literature`, the generated PDF has `Literature I` in the heading instead. How can I get rid of that number?

Comment: Does it have more than one page? If yes, that number could be to inform that it continues on the next frame.

Comment: @Sigur nope, that's the last slide

Comment: I have absolutely no idea about lyx, but in normal beamer I would guess this might be caused be a superfluous `allowframebreaks`.

Comment: Whereas LyX make a good job with other LaTeX classes, IMHO support of Beamer presentation in version 2.1 is a pain, even worse that in the past. Much better edit plain LaTeX in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `allowframebreaks` option from the frame, which includes the literature.